# Drawing NSView's subviews manually

Tags: cocoa, drawing, core-animation, core-graphics, nsview

I'm writing a custom NSView that needs to animate its subviews by applying NSAffineTransformation before drawing them.

I am looking for a method that draws the view's subviews so I can override it
in a way like that:

```
-(void)drawSubview:(NSView*)subview {
    [[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[self affineTrasformForSubview: subview] concat];
    [subview drawRect: subview.bounds];
    [[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Each of the subviews is responsible for drawing itself; your NSView subclass can have no control over what they do.

Comment: @Jay I want to apply the transform before for creating custom animation. Maybe it's possible to do that with layers?

Comment: @Ben-Uri Yes, I suppose that's what you'd want to do instead. Helps to know the overall goal, like : *Hey, I'd like to tilt the window contents by 90 degrees*, etc.

Comment: You can force a sub-view (or yourself) to redraw by calling `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: @trojanfoe setNeedsDisplay is not related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

for rotating: NSView setFrameCenterRotation:angle

for scaling: NSView scaleUnitSquareToSize:size

for more than rotating and scaling you would need to make your view a layer backed one and mess around with the layer, even though that is against apple recommendation. But I wouldn't worry too much about that and I think it is worth a try.